# How to rotate an canvas object while the object stays on the same place

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I am creating a Javascript game. It is about a guy who stands on top of the world. I already have an earth and now I need to rotate it but when I rotate it it also changes it place.

[image: Earth]
[image: Earth]

As you can see the earth rotates but it also changes its place. I want it to rotate just like the rotate keyframes from css. Any thoughts?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css"/>
</head>
<body onload="draw()">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    
setInterval(draw, 10);
function draw() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
    ctx.rotate(1*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.drawImage(img,canvas.width/2-200,canvas.height/2-100,300,300);
  };
  img.src = "earth.png";
}
</script>
</html>
```

**The code doesn't work because it cant load the image because i have it downloaded but now you guys have the code so you can see the problem.**

Comment: Code? It is probably rotating around the origin instead of around it's own center.

Comment: I updated it @Arg0n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/zcwfes9t/4/) fiddle

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

JavaScript

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var img;

function draw() {
  img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    setInterval(rotate, 10);
  };
  img.src = "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/13/55/earth-147591_960_720.png";
}

draw();

var i = 0;
function rotate() {
  i += 1;
  drawRotatedImage(img, 100, 100, 200, 200, i);
}

var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180; 
function drawRotatedImage(image, x, y, width, height, angle) { 
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(angle * TO_RADIANS);
  ctx.drawImage(image, -width/2, -height/2, width, height);
  ctx.restore(); 
}
```

Comment: @MartijnVenvande No problem, enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

A quicker way that avoids having to use save and restore.

If you are drawing 100's or 1000's of images (such as for games) the use of save and restore can make the difference between playable and not. In some situations the restore call can drop the frame rate for a nice 60fps to less than 10fps.

Always be careful when using save and restore, making sure you don't have large patterns, or filters ( if supported), complex gradients, or detailed fonts when you save. You are better to remove these thing before you do the save and restore if you plan to do many of them

For single images it does not matter and the previous answer is the best solution.

General purpose sprite render with scales rotation and fade

```
// draws a image centered at x,y scaled by sx,sy rotate (r in radians) and faded by alpha (0-1)and 

    function drawImage(image,x,y,sx,sy,r,alpha){ // 
        ctx.setTransform(sx,0,0,sy,x,y);
        ctx.rotate(r);
        ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
        ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.height/2);
    }
```

and without fade

```
    function drawImage(image,x,y,sx,sy,r){ // 
        ctx.setTransform(sx,0,0,sy,x,y);
        ctx.rotate(r);
        ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.height/2);
    }
```

or if you want to have the default transform after the call

```
    function drawImage(image,x,y,sx,sy,r){ // 
        ctx.setTransform(sx,0,0,sy,x,y);
        ctx.rotate(r);
        ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.height/2);
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    }
```

As you may want to render many images in a row you can restore the canvas context with

```
function restoreContext(){
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is useful.

Comment: @MartijnVenvande I just wrote a more detailed answer to very similar question that you may find useful as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/38079796/3877726