# HTML5 Canvas save() and restore() performance

Tags: html, performance, canvas

So the issue that I'm having is that in developing an HTML5 canvas app I need to use a lot of transformations (i.e. translate, rotate, scale) and therefore a lot of calls being made to context.save() and context.restore(). The performance drops very quickly even with drawing very little (because the save() and restore() are being called as many times as possible in the loop). Is there an alternative to using these methods but still be able to use the transformations? Thank you!

Comment: sure, if all you need is to reset the transformation matrix, then all you need is `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`. Remember that each call to `ctx.save()` will stack all the context's properties and that it will be freed only when calling `ctx.restore()`, so make sure that for every `save()` you've got a `restore()` being called.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I realized that the transformations themselves are expensive.. which I don't understand because they should be optimized to be able to be applied many many times as many games will require them heavily.

Comment: hum no, transformations shouldn't be expensive, I think you'll need to show us a snippet with an [mcve]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Animation and Game performance tips.

**Avoid save restore**

Use setTransform as that will negate the need for save and restore.

There are many reasons that save an restore will slow things down and these are dependent on the current GPU && 2D context state. If you have the current fill and/or stroke styles set to a large pattern, or you have a complex font / gradient, or you are using filters (if available) then the save and restore process can take longer than rendering the image.

When writing for animations and games performance is everything, for me it is about sprite counts. The more sprites I can draw per frame (60th second) the more FX I can add, the more detailed the environment, and the better the game.

I leave the state open ended, that is I do not keep a detailed track of the current 2D context state. This way I never have to use save and restore.

**ctx.setTransform rather than ctx.transform**

Because the transforms functions transform, rotate, scale, translate multiply the current transform, they are seldom used, as i do not know what the transform state is.

To deal with the unknown I use setTransform that completely replaces the current transformation matrix. This also allows me to set the scale and translation in one call without needing to know what the current state is.

```
ctx.setTransform(scaleX,0,0,scaleY,posX,posY); // scale and translate in one call
```

I could also add the rotation but the javascript code to find the x,y axis vectors (the first 4 numbers in setTransform) is slower than rotate.

**Sprites and rendering them**

Below is an expanded sprite function. It draws a sprite from a sprite sheet, the sprite has x & y scale, position, and center, and as I always use alpha so set alpha as well

```
// image is the image. Must have an array of sprites
// image.sprites = [{x:0,y:0,w:10,h:10},{x:20,y:0,w:30,h:40},....]
// where the position and size of each sprite is kept
// spriteInd is the index of the sprite
// x,y position on sprite center
// cx,cy location of sprite center (I also have that in the sprite list for some situations)
// sx,sy x and y scales
// r rotation in radians
// a alpha value
function drawSprite(image, spriteInd, x, y, cx, cy, sx, sy, r, a){
    var spr = image.sprites[spriteInd];
    var w = spr.w;
    var h = spr.h;
    ctx.setTransform(sx,0,0,sy,x,y); // set scale and position
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.globalAlpha = a;
    ctx.drawImage(image,spr.x,spr.y,w,h,-cx,-cy,w,h); // render the subimage
}
```

On just an average machine you can render 1000 +sprites at full frame rate with that function. On Firefox (at time of writing) I am getting 2000+ for that function (sprites are randomly selected sprites from a 1024 by 2048 sprite sheet) max sprite size 256 * 256

But I have well over 15 such functions, each with the minimum functionality to do what I want. If it is never rotated, or scaled (ie for UI) then

```
function drawSprite(image, spriteInd, x, y, a){
    var spr = image.sprites[spriteInd];
    var w = spr.w;
    var h = spr.h;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y); // set scale and position
    ctx.globalAlpha = a;
    ctx.drawImage(image,spr.x,spr.y,w,h,0,0,w,h); // render the subimage
}
```

Or the simplest play sprite, particle, bullets, etc

```
function drawSprite(image, spriteInd, x, y,s,r,a){
    var spr = image.sprites[spriteInd];
    var w = spr.w;
    var h = spr.h;
    ctx.setTransform(s,0,0,s,x,y); // set scale and position
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.globalAlpha = a;
    ctx.drawImage(image,spr.x,spr.y,w,h,-w/2,-h/2,w,h); // render the subimage
}
```

if it is a background image

```
function drawSprite(image){
    var s = Math.max(image.width / canvasWidth, image.height / canvasHeight); // canvasWidth and height are globals
    ctx.setTransform(s,0,0,s,0,0); // set scale and position
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0); // render the subimage
}
```

It is common that the playfield can be zoomed, panned, and rotated. For this I maintain a closure transform state (all globals above are closed over variables and part of the render object)

```
// all coords are relative to the global transfrom
function drawGlobalSprite(image, spriteInd, x, y, cx, cy, sx, sy, r, a){
    var spr = image.sprites[spriteInd];
    var w = spr.w;
    var h = spr.h;
    // m1 to m6 are the global transform
    ctx.setTransform(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6); // set playfield
    ctx.transform(sx,0,0,sy,x,y); // set scale and position
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.globalAlpha = a * globalAlpha; (a real global alpha)
    ctx.drawImage(image,spr.x,spr.y,w,h,-cx,-cy,w,h); // render the subimage
}
```

All the above are about as fast as you can get for practical game sprite rendering.

**General tips**

Never use any of the vector type rendering methods (unless you have the spare frame time) like, fill, stroke, filltext, arc, rect, moveTo, lineTo as they are an instant slowdown. If you need to render text create a offscreen canvas, render once to that, and display as a sprite or image.

**Image sizes and GPU RAM**

When creating content, always use the power rule for image sizes. GPU handle images in sizes that are powers of 2. (2,4,8,16,32,64,128....) so the width and height have to be a power of two. ie 1024 by 512, or 2048 by 128 are good sizes.

When you do not use these sizes the 2D context does not care, what it does is expand the image to fit the closest power. So if I have an image that is 300 by 300 to fit that on the GPU the image has to be expanded to the closest power, which is 512 by 512. So the actual memory footprint is over 2.5 times greater than the pixels you are able to display. When the GPU runs out of local memory it will start switching memory from mainboard RAM, when this happens your frame rate drops to unusable.

Ensuring that you size images so that you do not waste RAM will mean you can pack a lot more into you game before you hit the RAM wall (which for smaller devices is not much at all).

**GC is a major frame theef**

One last optimisation is to make sure that the GC (garbage collector) has little to nothing to do. With in the main loop, avoid using new (reuse and object rather than dereference it and create another), avoid pushing and popping from arrays (keep their lengths from falling) keep a separate count of active items. Create a custom iterator and push functions that are item context aware (know if an array item is active or not). When you push you don't push a new item unless there are no inactive items, when an item becomes inactive, leave it in the array and use it later if one is needed.

There is a simple strategy that I call a fast stack that is beyond the scope of this answer but can handle 1000s of transient (short lived) gameobjects with ZERO GC load. Some of the better game engines use a similar approch (pool arrays that provide a pool of inactive items).

GC should be less than 5% of your game activity, if not you need to find where you are needlessly creating and dereferencing.

Comment: Thanks for this it provided a lot of insight. However, the game I am creating (and this may sound strange), unlike other games, uses little sprites and is mostly using paths (moveTo, arcTo, lineTo, etc.) and the stroke method and properties such as shadowBlur for glow effects and others. In other words, my game mostly needs the native functionality and not sprites or sprite sheets. So to get a stronger glow I would redo the path and stroke it multiple times with a shadowBlur set to something and basically do these sorts of things. My performance drop is actually related to this..

Comment: With using sprites you also have to account for multiple resolutions and if you just scale them in your code then you get distortions on your sprites you don't want. You would have to do something similar to Android development in which you have multiples of the same sprite (& spritesheets) in different sizes so that on different screens/resolutions it will look like what you want it to look like. If you try using sprites for special effects (e,g glow) then they will look bad on resolutions that you weren't developing on, which in the real world will happen often.

Comment: @TheMAAAN The vast majority of imagery is done with SVG source images, and render scripts. You render the sprite sheets as needed on the client at the resolution that suits the device. this also allows for you to skip animation frames for devices with low memory and refresh rates. If you need colour changing you pre render 3 sprites RGB and mix them with comp lighten. Gradients, glows, shadows etc are low res, 16*16 pixels and have the benefit of blurring built in with bilinear filtering. Bitmap rendering provides such a performance benefit over vector its well worth the effort

Comment: So your saying all the scaling is done with SVG so quality isn't impacted and then rendered as bitmaps in the actual game? And what do you mean gradients and glows and low res?

Comment: Even so, is there any way you know in which you can gain good performance while being able to use the native paths methods such as stroke heavily along with shadows? Switching to using sprites would make what I am trying to do very difficult because of the fact that with sprites I would manually have to find a way to connect them (probably by per-pixel calculations).

Comment: @TheMAAAN If you have a background that is a gradient, you can either create a gradient  and render it with fillRect(...) which is slow or render it to a bitmap that has just enough pixels to hold the colours. A 1 by 2 pixel sprite can do a full screen High res background that you can not pick is not a standard gradient. Using paths you are facing many issues, (some devices are VERY bad at rendering them) All you can do is keep the count down and opt for a lower frame rate 30fps or 25/20fps.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info! I will probably have to switch to another method then unfortunately.

Comment: What is the `ctx.drawSprite()` method used in the last line of all of your functions? Should that be `ctx.drawImage()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh thanks for pointing that out... Yes should be drawImage.. I have done the same thing for all the functions. will correct that now.

Comment: @Frank A fast stack is not a linked list. Its like a standard stack (array) but only ever grows and is initialized to an approximate size to hold all elements and filled with preallocated (instantiated but inactive) item references `length` property is only used to determine if a new item is added or if to use the existing item on the stack at position `size` a property holding the top of stack. Elements in the stack are never dereferenced and require an init function to reuse. There are various ways to iterate items, one of which ensure size always points to the last + 1 active item.

Comment: So the memory never moves and nothing is ever garbage collected. This has me rethinking the way I do object pooling. For example, I can split 1,000 particles between 2 arrays, one for active, which will hold the particles I draw, and one for inactive, which will hold the particles that do nothing. Nothing gets garbage collected and I only iterate over the particles that need drawing, but I'm moving them around a lot. Are you saying: don't move them around and iterate over all 1,000, ignoring inactive particles and drawing active ones? It's the cost of iterating and checking vs memory moving.

Comment: @Frank You only need to iterate over active items in the one array. When you iterate use two indexes `head = 0`, and `tail = 0` rather than `i`. Process item, if still active increment head and tail, If item becomes inactive, increment only head. If `head !== tail` swap items in head and tail. Do this untill `head == array.size`. Then set `array.size = tail` You only swap the reference (64 or 32bit word) and you only iterate active items. The inactive items bubble up to the end of the array. This has a zero GC overhead. (Note since answer GC performance has improved dramatically)

Comment: I'll have to implement that to really understand it, but it sounds like a great idea. It's still moving memory around, but the block of memory always stays in the same place and the size never changes. I bet that is super fast. Thanks for telling me about it. Also, thanks for the post. Your examples with setTransform are really coming in handy. I had always done my scaling with CSS or drawImage and my translations were always calculated in the dest x, y of drawImage. This looks a lot cleaner and doesn't feel so hacky.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks, I just do not get in general the benefit to draw a sprite on a transformed canvas over draw a transformed sprite on the canvas. For example to draw a rotated sprite, you do not rotate the sprite, but you rotate the canvas... Or am I wrong?

Comment: @camillo777 We set the transformation matrix that is applied to content as it is drawn on the canvas, The canvas is not transformed.