# Is it a good practice to create new objects outside of the main animation loop in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, requestanimationframe

In HTML5 we usually use `requestAnimationFrame` to animate the shapes or objects. But is it a good practice to create these shapes and objects outside of the animate function?

Say I have a function

```
function animate() {
  renderA();
  renderB();
  requestAnimateionFrame(animate);
}
```

and I have a pre-allocated array outside of `animate()` defined as:

```
let arr = new Array(99999);
let currentIndex = 4999;
```

Say the actual length of arr is 5000, the rest of the array is `undefined`.

Now I want to insert some new objects into the array, can I change the animate function to this?

```
function animate() {
  renderA();
  let length = 100;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      arr[currentIndex + 1 + i] = new SomeObject({...});
  }
  currentIndex += length;
  renderB();
  requestAnimateionFrame(animate);
}
```

If I remember correctly in this example the `animate` function will be called multiple times during canvas animation. So if I create a new object inside this `animate()` function and then render it afterwards the resources will eventually drain up? Is it OK to create new object inside the animation loop?

Comment: If you need new objects then create new objects. If you need temporary objects and don't keep references to them they should be garbage-collected. Where do you think you could create objects from if *not* from within the animation loop (including from functions called from the loop)?

Comment: @nnnnnn so it is alright to create new objects inside `animate`? What about hundreds of them every time? I suspect the function will be called many times a second so the resource usage would be huge. I mean create objects and put them in an array outside of `animate` and then use them in the function.

Comment: @nnnnnn, and garbage collection is one of the slowest thing a browser can do... Don't do it in an animation. Instead, prepare your objects first, modify it in your animation, but avoid at all cost to create new ones during the animation loop. Here is a [good reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069462/html5-canvas-save-and-restore-performance/38079796#38079796). Ps: "*Where do you think you could create objects from if not from within the animation loop*" => all good animation has an `init method`

Comment: @kaiido - Sure, where possible pool/reuse the objects. Though my mention of garbage collection has distracted from what I meant to ask: what if there is a need to create *additional* objects while keeping existing ones alive? (E.g., in a game where enemies multiply.) Would you suggest pre-creating the maximum possible number of objects (assuming there is a maximum)?

Comment: no. I would suggest keeping an array of enemies, set a property `alive` to all of them, when a new one should come, take the place of a dead one, by only updating its properties. If and only if there is none, then push a new one in the array. Relying on GC is one of the worst thing for js animations.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes I also have this question in mind. I am using pre-allocated array now but I wonder if I create any objects inside the animation loop will it slow down the animation very quickly? Hopefully someone already has that kind of experience before.

Comment: @Kaiido I agree with you. This is what I am doing now. But occasionally I forgot and created some new object inside the loop because it is so intuitive to do that so this question just come up.

Comment: @Kaiido as per your last comment if I need to push a new object in a pre-set array I still need to create a new object inside the loop? Is there any other way? Like using some kind of event trigger? Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: It really depends on the kind of animation you're doing. If we're talking about a game, of course, use events and user interaction to trigger these changes. Your rendering loop should not have to take care of your game logic. Separate these.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes I am talking about writing a game. Do you have any suggestion on resources or materials I can read in more details?