# How to increase canvas perfomance

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, memory

I wanna to scale the game from 1 ship to fleet of 10 000 ships if it is posible to milion of ships.

Canvas drawing all what you tell him to draw even if it is negative coordinates. So I draw only game objects which is in the display range.

I used everywhere ES5 which is faster and more supported.
Scaling and rotation calculation is made by Camera, Mouse and KeyBoard events (cant apply only for rockets and laser beams).

But the main time is used by this part of code which used for each game object in display range (there can be thousands game objects or few):

```
`ctx.save()
ctx.translate(drawX, drawY);
ctx.rotate(alfa);
ctx.drawImage(images.image, -width/2, -height/2, width, height);
ctx.restore()`
```

How can I make it faster?

What is the best thing to do to increase perfomance?
Now I thinkg about removing `ctx.rotate(alfa)` and rotate image based on events and use rotated image and resizing that image with current scale (only for objects in display range).

Thanks.

Comment: Providing a JSFiddle or related medium would be helpful for trouble shooting.

Comment: I dont know all my images is not legal and copypasted from starsector and other games:) without images it will not work

Comment: Will make some example later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably going to run into hard limits if you try to render some thousands, let alone a million, of independent things in 2d canvas alone. You would probably be better using WebGL, perhaps with a library like [PixiJS](http://www.pixijs.com/).

However, if you still plan on using canvas, [user Blindman67 gave some good tips regarding performance in a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38079796/5313009). In short, to your case, avoid using `save`/`restore` and use `setTransform` instead, and draw images with dimensions that are power of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, Cant vote up your answer my reputation is too low:) Hundred now is not a problem even with thousand I think can make but make update every 40ms.

Comment: Your answer is very good. And link is like a paradise, THANKS:)

Comment: I tried to do it with unity but I think unity is so fast as I think for 2d and collisions is used so much resources in Android I cant run more that 9 ships (1player and 8 enemies) . I dont  think I will make it faster with WebGL:) Canvas is more easy to learn and write for me.